# Proving a holomorphic function is constant under some conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose $\mathbb D$ be the unit open disk and $f\in H(\mathbb D)$ and let $u=\operatorname{Re}(f)$, $v=\operatorname{Im}(f)$.
Then i need to show that if $|u|+|v|=1$ at every point of $\mathbb D$ then $f$ is constant.

i was trying to apply Rouche's Theorem, but i am not able to get it.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was not constant, by the open mapping theorem $f(\mathbb{D})$ would be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb C$. But, since $|u|+|v|=1$,$$f(\mathbb{D})\subset\{x+yi\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,x,y\in\mathbb{R}\wedge|x|+|y|=1\},$$which contains no non-empty open set (it's the square whose vertices are $\pm1$ and $\pm i$).

Comment: why it does not contain any non-empty open set? as ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ can be in the square.

Comment: @Sahab When I wrote “square”, what I had in mind was a pogygonal line, not a $2$-dimensional region.

Comment: i did not get it

Comment: @Sahab My “square” is the union of four line segments: one joining $1$ to $i$, another one joining $i$ to $-1$, another one joining $-1$ to $-i$ and finally another one joining $-i$ to $1$. An union of four line segments contains no open set.

Comment: ok just adding to it what should be the answer if $|u|+|v|<1$ everywhere except at some point where it will be equal to 1.